# Are there any API endpoints to check whether DAGs are PAUSESD / UNPAUSED?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've been following this repo https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin to play around AIRFLOW using APIs. The thing is, there is no REST API Endpoint to **CHECK** whether a DAG is Paused or Unpaused. But there are ENDPOINTS to PAUSE / UNPAUSE DAGs. Are there any API endpoints to check whether a DAG is paused or unpaused?

**Note : Not through Command Line**

Comment: Do you mean to check the DAGs in WEB UI to check the status of them?

Comment: No!. An API Endpoint that tells whether the DAG is Paused/Unpaused.